# How to collect 3 arrays in 1 array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => l_ka3a1
    [1] => l_ka3a2
    [2] => l_ka3a3
)
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => l_no_inspection
    [1] => l_elbab_alresi
    [2] => l_bab_alqa3a
)
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => notes
    [1] => notes
    [2] => null
)
```

I want to collect them in 1 array:

```
Array(
    Array
    (
        [0] => l_ka3a1
        [1] => l_no_inspection
        [2] => notes
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => l_ka3a2
        [1] => l_elbab_alresi
        [2] => notes
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => l_ka3a3
        [1] => l_bab_alqa3a
        [2] => null
    )
)
```

witch every index in old arrays with the same one in another and collect them in 1 array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to creating new array contain target three arrays.

```
$newArr = array_map(function($v1, $v2, $v3){
    return [$v, $v2, $v3];
}, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/U0Uo2)

Answer (score 0):

**One of many ways** using simple `for` loop,

```
$expected = [];
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $expected[] = [$arr1[$i],$arr2[$i],$arr3[$i]];
}
print_r($expected);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/9Oo5D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which one do you like. But for me, I will do like this.

```
$array = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
```

OR I will make it more dynamic using [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
  $array = [];
  array_push($array, $arr1);
  // Some code maybe
  array_push($array, $arr2);
  // Some code maybe
  array_push($array, $arr3);
```

Comment: Please pay attention to how array elements are combined. In your case you just put the 3 arrays to one larger array, but in the question arrays are joined in a  different way.